# If this warped coin is flipped 5 times, what is the probability that more heads than tails occur?

Tags: probability

A warped coin has probability of 0.5 of landing Heads, probability of 0.4 of landing Tails, and probability 0.1 of landing on its Edge. It is flipped 5 times. What is the probability that more Heads occur than Tails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. probability of 3-5 heads, plus
2. probability of 2 heads and 0-1 tails, plus
3. probability of 1 head and 0 tails.

Comment: oops, for some reason, I thought it was flipped 10 times. Duh.